# How to fix “<string> DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence” in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am using pytest-3/python3

```
def check_email(email):
    **regex = '^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$'**
    if(re.search(regex,email)):  
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The ** part is what gave an error

Answer (score 2):

Use a **raw string**

```
regex = r'^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$'
```

Note the `r` prefix.  This ensures that the `\` are not interpreted as possible escape sequences and instead just as plain `\`.

As `\` is meaningful in regular expressions, it is a good habit in python to **always use raw strings for regular expressions**. (See the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) documentation)

Answer (score 1):

The usage of "\~" is not printing literally a "\~" but will be reduced to an escape sequence much like '\n' is a New-Line Character. You can use for example `"\\w"` to achieve a literal "\w".

Or you can preprend the whole string with an r like `r'your \string'`